# Why is the background image not changing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var ss = document.getElementById("slideshow");
var a = "url('http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg')";
var b = "url('http://mediafiles.allaboutsymbian.com/808/zeiss/g.jpg')";
var c = "url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkqtidhhgFl5ZXd_RLpjXjD60S5s1OHA6nM9WffYBlk-JQMyF2')";
var d = "url('http://thehinduimages.com/admin/images/pimages/p9e4dd9e.jpg')";
var i = 2;

function fade() {
  loop: for (i; i < 5; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      case 1:
        document.getElementById("slideshow").style.backgroundImage = a;
        break;
      case 2:
        document.getElementById("slideshow").style.backgroundImage = b;
        break;
      case 3:
        document.getElementById("slideshow").style.backgroundImage = c;
        break;
      case 4:
        document.getElementById("slideshow").style.backgroundImage = d;
        i = 0;
        break;
    }
    i++;
    break loop;
  }
}
setInterval(fade, 3500);


function change() {
  if (ss.style.backgroundImage == '') ss.style.backgroundImage = a;
  else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == a) ss.style.backgroundImage = d;
  else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == b) ss.style.backgroundImage = a;
  else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == c) ss.style.backgroundImage = b;
  else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == d) ss.style.backgroundImage = c;

}
```

```css
#a1 {
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid lime;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 94%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<p id="slideshow" style="background-image: url(' http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg ')">
</p>
<div onclick="change();" id="a1">
</div>
```

The green arrow should change the background image. However, ss returns null while debugging. How can I solve this issue so that the image changes everytime i click the triangle?

P.S. I used the background-image property in inline code but still there is no effect.

Comment: Make a debug output of what `ss.style.backgroundImage` _actually_ contains.

Comment: It shows that `ss.style.backgroundImage` is null. How can I solve this issue? I tried shifting the `background-image` property in-line with the `<p>` tag. Still it isn't solving the issue.

Comment: You can only read styles via `element.style.propertyname` if those styles where either set inline via style attribute, or have been set via JS before already.

Comment: @CBroe But I changed the style to inline with the style attribute. It still shows the ss is null.

Comment: Provide a complete, testable example please. [mcve]

Comment: @CBroe edited the question.

Comment: You did _not_ set a background-image via style attribute so far - your HTML is invalid, because of the quotes. The content of the style attribute of that element is currently `background-image: url(`

Comment: @CBroe Fixed the issue with quotes. Still not working.

Comment: Again: Make a debug output of what the property _actually_ contains at that point - then you will see the difference. // You can not rely on browsers returning style values the same way you set them. You should not be comparing style values, but rather use classes to apply the styling in the first place. Asking whether an element has a certain class does not have this problem of ambiguous return values.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. But somehow on calling the change the backgroundimage is null. So adding a null condition solves your problem.

```
function change() {
if (ss.style.backgroundImage == '') ss.style.backgroundImage = a;
else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == a) ss.style.backgroundImage = d;
else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == b) ss.style.backgroundImage = a;
else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == c) ss.style.backgroundImage = b;
else if (ss.style.backgroundImage == d) ss.style.backgroundImage = c;00
}
change()
```

Comment: It still shows that ss is null. The function is still not working as desired.

Comment: I think the images are not loaded by the time you call the function. Try calling it on window load.

Answer (score 0):

Is change() doing the same thing as fade()?

Can't you just do something like this:

```
function change() {
  fade();
}
```

Comment: change() changes the image when called by clicking an element. fade() changes it automatically after every 3500 milliseconds.